# How to Include CData using LINQ to XML?

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I want to record to a XML with below those codes in ASP.Net.However,I want to add  `<![[CDATA]]>`  in the fifth element.
  when I making it as shown below, it's creating `""&"bt;"`instead of `>` character and `""&"lt;"`instead of `<` character  to XML.
 How to get rid of that problem?

Code:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("photo",
        new XElement("thumbnail", TextBox1.Text),
        new XElement("filename", TextBox2.Text),
        new XElement("baslik1", TextBox3.Text),
        new XElement("baslik2", TextBox4.Text),
        new XElement("description","<>"+TextBox5.Text),
        new XElement("link", TextBox6.Text),
        new XElement("fiyat1", TextBox7.Text),
        new XElement("indorani", TextBox8.Text));

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/satislar.xml"));

doc.Root.Add(xml);

doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/satislar.xml"));

Response.Write("kayıt eklendi");
new XElement("description","<>"+TextBox5.Text),
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
new XElement("description",
    new XCData("<>" + TextBox5.Text)),
```

in place of your current

```
new XElement("description", "<>" + TextBox5.Text),
```

line.