# Serializing an object to XML and including a CDATA section

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Include CData using LINQ to XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784337/how-to-include-cdata-using-linq-to-xml)

About a month ago I wrote a post about wrapping some data within CDATA tags for a webservice (it's their requirement, not mine). I had done a bunch of troubleshooting and worked to an example that provided some results. 
(see post [Problems serializing a class to XML and including a CDATA section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471676/problems-serializing-a-class-to-xml-and-including-a-cdata-section) for the code and results )

Now I have realized that the class design was terrible to say the least and have rewritten most of the code I had written previously. As such it has taken some time to get back to the same question I had before.

For the sake of post brevity I have decided to ask a new question and leave the old one as is.

**My (revised ) question**

Am I able to use XmlDocument to create the elements up to the CDATA section, and then use the `CreateCDataSection()` method to create the CDATA section as below?

```
<UpdateOrderStatus> 
    <Action>2</Action> 
        <Value> 
            <![CDATA[ 
                <Shipment> 
                    <Header> 
                        <SellerID>
                            ...
             ]]>
         </Value>
 </UpdateOrderStatus>
```

I am able to serialize my existing objects into the proper XML fragment, however I am not 100% certain on if this code is correct or if there is a better way:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment();
xmlDoc.CreateElement("Shipment");
xmlDoc.CreateElement("Action");
xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("2");
xmlDoc.CreateElement("Value");
xmlDoc.CreateCDataSection(orderToUpdate);
```

If you were programming this, how would you go about it? I don't necessarily need code, unless the concept can only be shown that way. A class name, or a MSDN reference etc would be fine

Comment: Look at this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784337/how-to-include-cdata-using-linq-to-xml

Comment: @Vasiliy if you add your link as an answer I will give you the answer.