# Invalid characters in XML despite using XDocument

Tags: .net, xml

I try to write a little program to export data from an SQL database to XML (and later on to import the same data in another database).
For that I get the schema of the tables in question, read all the data from the tables and putting it into an XML structure to save when done with all the tables.

I use the `XDocument` as the XML structure.

```
Dim result As XDocument
Dim element As XElement
Dim item As XElement

result = New XDocument(New XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"))
element = New XElement("table", New XAttribute("name", <variable holding the table name>))
result.Add(element)

item = New XElement("item")
element.Add(item)

item.Add(New XAttribute(<variable holding the column name>, <variable holding the column data>))
...
```

So far, so good.

Using the `XDocument` even seems to take care of masking special characters (so I thought).

But now I get an error because the value of one of the string columns I'd like to export contains an invalid character (`ChrW(1)`). The error doesn't happen when adding the `XAttribute` with the invalid data, it happens when trying to save the XML content to a file or when getting the XML content via `ToString`.
After hours of inspecting the data I found out which table and which data item contains the invalid characters, but how do I have to mask them to be able to export them to XML? Is there any built in method or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784337/how-to-include-cdata-using-linq-to-xml

Comment: Putting "<>" infront of the value didn't help and putting the value inside a `XCData` object brings another error (an XObject can't be used as value).